# How to parse json output using java

Tags: java, json, parsing

How to parse json output using java with below scenorio.

I have json result (output) in `getDetails()` below is the json output for `getDetails()`

```
[{"myInfo":[{"name":"surya","mobile":"7893939393"}],"status":"active"}]
```

How I can return the 'mobile' value using java

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the Json syntax you miss in the end }] symbols. I use JsonArray because of your example. I am using org.json.JSONArray;

```
String json = "[{\"myInfo\":[{\"name\":\"surya\",\"mobile\":\"7893939393\"}]}]";

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONArray("myInfo")
                    .getJSONObject(0)
                    .get("mobile"));
```

Comment: List<NetworkInterface> json = instance.getNetworkInterfaces();



i have result in avobe method.
Getting error when i have implemented as you suggested.



error:
The constructor JSONArray(List<NetworkInterface>) is undefined
The method getJSONObject(int) is undefined for the type JSONArray

Comment: Got the solution. Thanks